# Alternative for panel in Portal Layout?

Tags: zk, zul

I'm trying to build a dashboard with drag-gable widgets. I am successful to achieve this using portal layout . But then I find it tough to customize the panel as easy as using DIV.

Is there any other way to achieve this with Div and have it integrated to portal layout instead of a panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<portalchildren>` only accepts `<panel>` as its child, and `<div>` is not allowed. If using `<div>`, you cannot maximize, collapse, and close each block.

What kind of customization you need?

You can refer to http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Customization_Guide for style customization.

If you want to add custom behavior, you can add event listeners on a panel or create a class that inherits ZK's Panel, then use your class for a panel.

or define it as a new component like , please refer to http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/Composite_Component#Define_Components_in_a_Language_Addon

Comment: My main concern about customization is the UI aspect . It helped Thanks .